# How to write a byte to register with specific memory address?

Tags: c, memory, byte, cpu-registers, memory-address

I want to write a byte to register with specific memory address (0x1228A432)

But, this register has a following structure:

```
 Bits  |   Access   |   Name   | Reset  | Description |
[31:8] | Read only  | -------- | ------ |  Reserved   |
[7:0]  | Read-write | REG[7:0] | 0xXX   | ----------- |
```

Please tell me, how to write a byte to this register without "touching" the Reserved bits?

EDIT1: My target is Cortex A9.
I could successfully read/write to onboard DDR2 memory using 256-bit values (such as 0xFF)

EDIT2: I used to work with DDR2 memory in the following way :

```
// First stage
static unsigned char *p = 0;
char * argv1="0x60000000";
unsigned long address=strtoul(argv1, 0, 0);
p = (unsigned char *) argv1;

// Second stage
char * argv4="FF";
int value=strtol(argv4,0,16);

// Third stage
int offset = 9;
p[offset]=value;
```

EDIT3: I found out the following information:

All registers are 32 bits wide and do not support byte writes.
Write operations must be word-wide and bits marked as reserved must be preserved
using read-modify-write.

Comment: Is this for a microcontroller? Would `((uint8_t *)0x1228A432)[0] = 42;` suffice?

Comment: It very much depends on the architecture of choice. Is byte-wide access allowed? Some microcontrollers (e.g. STM32) have extra  means for setting/resetting selected bits in e.g. PIO output register, without touching other bits. Let us know what's your target :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: @CodePainters My target is Cortex A9.

Comment: There is no 0x1228a432 memory-mapped register in the Cortex-A9 MP. [Cortex A9-Handbook](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0407e/DDI0407E_cortex_a9_mpcore_r2p0_trm.pdf) What version of the A9 are you using?

Comment: @RedX that is a register of a custom board attached to Cortex A9. I can read/write to DDR2 memory of this board using 256-values, but don't know how to do the same with byte (8-bit value) and register.

Comment: Without knowing details about the custom board's implementation of  registers and how the custom board is actually wired to the microprocessor it's almost impossible to do anything but guess at an answer here. Especially if H2CO3's answer about writing through a byte pointer doesn't work (it might be instructive to know exactly *how* it doesn't work).

Comment: @MichaelBurr please check my EDIT2 at the question. this works with custom board. But I need to do the same with register.

Comment: Code for DDR2 access is most likely irrelevant here. You need detailed information about your particular peripheral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to preserve bits [31:8], assuming 32-bit wide access, is to read the value, zero-out bits [7:0], bitwise-or it with the value needed and then write it back to the register.

Something like (stealing from RedX a bit ;) ):

```
uint8_t your_8_bit_value = 0x42;
uint32_t volatile * const mem_map_register = (uint32_t volatile *) 0x1228a432;
*mem_map_register = (*mem_map_register & 0xFFFFFF00) | your_8_bit_value;
```

Yet I think there should be more info available about your hardware. I've seen several datasheets saying e.g. that you have to write all 1 to reserved bits (meaning that reserved bits are reserved for future use, and 1 is a safe default), etc. So it is not always obvious, that leaving reserved bits untouched is the right thing to do.

You should find more details about your hardware - are byte-wide writes supported, are writes to reserved bits ignored perhaps, or should be all 0/1, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the assembler instruction handbook for an 8 bit writing instruction (not sure if it exists). If it does, use an uint8_t for your assignment to that memory location (`uint8_t volatile * const reg = (uint8_t volatile * const) 0x1228a432;`).

Else do what Omkant said. Overwriting the bits with the same number should not produce any unwanted results, since they are not "zeroed" before being overwritten.

His code in C (this is the verbose version for better readability):

```
uint8_t your_8_bit_value = 0x42;
uint32_t volatile * const mem_map_register = (uint32_t volatile *) 0x1228a432;
*mem_map_register = (*mem_map_register & 0xFFFFFF00) | your_8_bit_value;
```

Comment: Just tested, and it does not work as well. Please, could you provide at least one more way of doing it?

Comment: I used to work with DDR2 memory in the following way : 1) static unsigned char *p = 0; ---> char * argv1="0x00000008"; ---> unsigned long address=strtoul(argv1, 0, 0); ---> 2) p = (unsigned char *) argv1; ---> int offset = 9; ---> char * argv4="FF"; ---> value=strtol(argv4,0,16); ---> 3) p[offset]=value;

Comment: I don't think it is correct. The `new_register_value` in this code snippet is going to be simply 0x42, as `0xFFFFFFFF & v == v`. The `(*mem_map_register & new_register_value)` expression has all zeros on bits [31:8], so this code is effectively resetting those bits, not preserving them.

Answer (score 0):

```
[register value] = ([register value] | [00 00 00 FF]) & [FF FF FF XX]
```

Here , xx is the one byte read from your given address and then set a mask of 24 bits.
    And perform bitwise & on the values shown above
    I think this should work

Comment: Is it correct? (value | FF FF FF FF) gives all ones, then masked with FF FF FF XX, so you effectively write FF FF FF XX to the register - not exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: @CodePainters : Yes, You can do it like this .. anyway I have given just the idea of how to do this rather than providing the whole code.Since I am working on this kind of projects so I think this should work it's pretty much similar to setting and getting bits to a particular variable (here its register).

Comment: How come? Try `printf("0x%08x", (0x12345678 | 0xFFFFFFFF) & 0xFFFFFF42);` - it prints `0xffffff42`, confirming my previous comment - this code overwrites bits [31:8] with 1s.

Comment: @CodePainters is your "42" a hex value? in this case, it could not be put in a byte

Comment: Of course hex. Do you want to say `0x42` is to big for a byte? It's 01000010 binary, perfectly valid for 8 bits :) Or, what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, bit corrected .. donno What was I Thinking at that time. Sorry for that